# You have two airflow.cfg files

Tags: airflow

I have created a venv project and installed airflow with in this venv. I have also set the export AIRFLOW_HOME - to a directory ( airflow_home ) with in this venv project. First time, after I ran

$airflow version

this created airflow.cfg and logs directory under this 'airflow_home' folder. However, when I repeat the same on next day, now I have the error message that I have two airflow.cfg.

one airflow.cfg under my venv project

another one under /home/username/airflow/airflow.cfg

Why is that ? I haven't installed airflow anywhere outside this venv project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. If I don't set the environment variable AIRFLOW_HOME, by default it creates a new ariflow.cfg under `/home/usernme/airflow`. To avoid this, AIRFLOW_HOME should be set before calling airflow each time after terminal starts or add to bash profile.